# Logic if $x \bmod 3 ≠ 0$, then $3 \nmid x^2$

Tags: logic, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

[image: Image of the problem]

How would one go about writing out this proof?
Mod tends to confuse me, but my line of thought went to :

Perhaps proving by the contrapositive? Such as we would say: if 3|x^2, then x mod 3 = 0. But I am stuck as to where to go from here, or if contrapositive is even the way to go.

Comment: Contrapositive works; if $3|x^2$, then $3|x$

Comment: If $x\ne0\,mod3$ then $x=3k\pm1$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Lemma: If $a \equiv b\pmod{3}$ then $a^2 \equiv b^2\pmod{3}$.  This follows, since if $3 | (a-b)$ then $3 | (a^2 - b^2) = (a-b)(a+b).$ Therefore, by the Lemma, it is **sufficient** to manually check 
$x=1$ and $x=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\neq 0\pmod{3}$, then $x=1,2\pmod{3}$. Thus, $x^{2} = 1^{2},2^{2} = 1\neq 0\pmod{3}$.